# Apache - Request uri md5

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

Is it possible to create an md5 hash string of current request uri and assign it as a env variable so I can read it from PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't test, but you may try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap md5create prg:/usr/local/sbin/md5create.pl
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI} [E=MD5HASH:${md5create:$1}]
```

md5create.pl script to create md5sum

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for a basic cache using pure htaccess is to load from a cache that reflects the request URI, in effect you compile your files into the tree tructure that your dynamic URLs indicate.

For example:

```
Request: http://domain.com/foo/
```

File structure:

```
Top Level: index.php,cache/
[Inside the cache/ directory -->] index.php, foo/
```

You get the idea - it's like you're building a static site, but you've stored the cached version of the site inside a 'cache' folder.

Then your .htaccess

```
# Add cache directory to request, store original request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/?$ /cache/$1 [E=orig:$1]

# Does the request exist as a directory in the cache folder?
# Yes -> load the cached page
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME} [L]

# No -> continue with system rewrite
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/%{ENV:orig} [L]
```

Threw this together so could be improved, and relies on your cache directory being automatically populated as a file structure, but thought it might be useful as it's pure htaccess.

Your serverside scripts would need to updated the cache filestructure and do the housekeeping.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that by using the global variable `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` and use the internal PHP `md5()` function to generate that.

If you want to execute that every single time just add the php code to the `auto_prepend_file` variable in php.ini.

Comment: I need that variable first inside apache because I need to do some check with mod_rewrite. 
eg:  
RewriteCond page_cache/%{MD5_STRING}.html -f  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page_cache/%{MD5_STRING}.html [L]  
  
I tried to generate md5 string using RewriteMap and c++ executable..but Apache simply won't start when using that RewriteMap...I still haven't figured out why.
So I'm trying to avoid the RewriteMap

Comment: I see where you're going with that one, but I'm afraid mod_rewrite doesn't do any advanced scripting functions as the one you're requesting, normal policy I've seen for this kind of page_cache is to use a front-end PHP to check if the file exists and if so just fread() that directly

Comment: Yes, but if I manage to avoid PHP I can get up to 300% more req/sec. I'll try to enable my RewriteMap, thanks for your help anyway (I'll probably have more questions later :) ).

Comment: No problem, good luck ;)